# Create tile / secondary tile from a desktop app

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I would like to create a custom tile for my Windows Forms Application.

I found that the `Secondary Tile` is in the `Microsoft.UI.StartScreen` namespace witch isn't available in WinForms.

So how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatley normal desktop applications cannot, by design, create custom tiles on the start screen. The best one can do is to optimize the executable's icon for the tile format as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj673981

Comment: but there are programs that do this, like OblyTile ( http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1899865 )

Comment: If you actually read the description of the program, you'll see that it's not actually creating secondary tiles. It's just creating extra shortcuts.